# A question about non-constract map

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ a compact metric space,let $f:X \rightarrow X$,such that:

$$ |x-y| \leq |f(x)-f(y)|$$

Now I want to prove that $f$ is isometry.

I can only prove that $f(X)$ is dense in $X$ , otherwise  pick $z$,such that 
$$d(z,f(X)) > \epsilon >0$$

Then we get a sequence $\{ f^k (z) \}$,which can not have a convergent subsequence,which contradict with compactness of $X$.

But I don't know how to complete the problem.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: injectivity follows but is the map surjective?

Comment: Shouldn't that condition be written as $d(x,y) \leq d(f(x),f(y))$?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to cover the space as efficiently as possible with small balls, and look at what $f$ does to such coverings.  A complete solution to this problem can be found [here](https://people.math.osu.edu/memoli.2/courses/cse-topics-2014/background.pdf).